# My SQL query works as expected in SQL Server, but when running it in Visual Studio, it doesn't. What happened?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, dataset

I am trying to create an application on Visual Studio 2015, where I connect to a database and display the results on a DataGridView. It includes a search bar I included through the DataGridView Tasks screen, that filters the DataGridView based on the search results.

I have a SQL query (filters database based on `FirstName`) attached to the DataGridView.

When I test search for just the first letter of the `FirstName` column, nothing shows up (it only returns the result if I type in the exact `FirstName` of one of the rows in my database). I concatenated the wildcard character on my SQL query, so even if I searched just by first letter of the first name, results should still show up.

What's going on?

The SQL query seems to be correct because I tested my query in SQL Server against my database, and when I added the query on my DataGridView (using the "Execute Query" button in "Query Builder"). It returns the expected results. I even double-checked the query in the dataset to make sure it's the exact query.

I'm connected to the database because I'm able to successfully display the dataset to my DataGridView.

The SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Doctor
WHERE  
    (FirstName LIKE @FirstName + '%')
```

When I search in the search bar, typing the letters (ex. "j", "je") don't show any results, but when I type a First Name exactly like it exists in the database (ex. "Jen"), the result shows up.

Since I have the "%" (wildcard) character concatenated to my query, searching by "j" and "je" doesn't work, but it should, shouldn't it?

Edit: I got this working yesterday. I don't think I changed any code (it's actually the default code that's generated when creating DataGridView and adding a query). The program stopped working as expected today, which is odd.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Editing the query to that doesn't work, and I copied and pasted it too

Comment: What happens if you type "Je"? (with a capital "J")

Comment: @forpas No results pull up when I run my program on Visual Studio. And typing "jen" (all lowercase) pulls the result into DataGridView.

Comment: Anyway try this: `upper(FirstName) LIKE upper(@FirstName) + '%'`

Comment: @forpas Thank you, it worked! However, I don't quite understand why it worked. Why does the field name and the search string need to be uppercase?

Comment: The SQL Server instance you use has a case sensitive collation. This means that LIKE treats `j` and `J` as different chars. Using for both the function UPPER() you can overpass this problem, since they will be both transformed to `J` so they are equal.

Comment: @forpas Thank you! Is that the same reason for using UPPER on FirstName? Isn't that just telling the query to uppercase the column name itself? If the field/column in the database is stylized as "FirstName", then why doesn't using "FirstName" works in the query, but UPPER(FirstName) does?

Comment: This: `'FirstName' LIKE 'FIR%'` returns FALSE so both must be capitalized

Comment: @forpas Thanks for the help! That clarified a lot!

Comment: If you have a datatype like `varchar` for your `FirstName` column, it has a **collation** - and those might be case sensitive. If they are, they match must be made using correct casing (upper-/lower-case).